# d3 input resets radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, input

I'm having a bar chart created with d3 that sorts itself whenever there's an input. I found it in the internet on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705.
It looks like that:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.frequency = +d.frequency;
 });

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

d3.select("input").on("change", change);

var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);

function change() {
clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

// Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
    ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
    : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
    .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
    .copy();

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .sort(function(a, b) { return x0(a.letter) - x0(b.letter); });

var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
    delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

transition.selectAll(".bar")
    .delay(delay)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d.letter); });

transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("g")
    .delay(delay);
}
});
```

I left out the CSS part as I don't think it matters. The problem is, that I also have multiple radio buttons in html like:

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" onclick="radios('finance.csv')" />
<label for="radio1">Financial Situation</label>
</div>
```

Whenever the bars sort themselves, the radio buttons reset themselves. So I click on a radio button. It is marked for a few seconds, and then it jumps back to the first radio button. I guess its because of the "input" parts in:

```
 d3.select("input").on("change", change);

var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);
```

How can I prevent the radios to reset themselves but still have my countries be sorted on input change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm very confused by your question.  The code you highlighted just causes the initial sort on page load.  It will also "check" the first radio button on page load after 2 seconds.  What are you attempting to do?  What does the `radios` function do?

Comment: Oh sorry I'm calling a function that actually updates the input data.tsv 
Whenever I call that method and the input changes, it reorganizes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.property` can be used as a getter or a setter. Here, you're using it as a setter, so when you do:

```
d3.select("input").property("checked", true)
```

You're *setting* all inputs to be checked. And since only one radio button is allowed to be checked, it checks the first.

I don't have the time to set up a fiddle and test, but I believe just using it as a getter would fix it:

```
d3.select("input").property("checked").each(change);
```

You could also be more precise with your selector:

```
d3.select("input[type=radio]:checked").each(change);
```

This has the benefit of not firing unpredictably if you add another input somewhere else on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The radio buttons work correctly now, but the bars do not sort themsleves at all.

Comment: Ack. If you can set it up in a fiddle I can play around with it :)